# What is the name of the Windows service that lists Systems Internals as the manufacturer?

Tags: windows, service, windows-10

This is a question that comes up in Task 2 (System Configuration) in TryHackMe's WINFUN2 v1.0 room. I am honestly (perhaps stupidly) stuck... Does anyone know the answer?

> What is the name of the Windows service that lists Systems Internals
> as the manufacturer?

Comment: The formulation of this task is sloppy. Much better would be 

'What is the name of the service that lists "Systems Internals" under the tab "Manufacturer"?'

Answer (score 9):

The question is asking specifically for a particular service. In the **System Configurations** window, there is a **Services** tab. Look through them and pay close attention to the **Manufacturer** column, you will see some key words that look very familiar. If you don't see it still here is the answer:

> PsShutdown

Answer (score 5):

To get a list of Windows Services, you need to open the *System Configuration utility* (run `msconfig`) and go to the ***Services*** tab (you will find many services there). It's a good idea to filter this list by checking the `Hide all Microsoft services` checkbox to make it easy to read and find what you're looking for. Pay attention to the Manufacturer column and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 4):

there is option that says hide all microsoft services if you check in they hide all microsoft services and now there is few services left there you see very easily which service is for system internal but i give you its name also its name is "
PsShutdown"

Answer (score 0):

Look for Ps.........n. As it is said in the previous answers look specifically in the Manufacturer column in the Windows VM (for sure your own System Config will be different)